# How to use linq to find ascending order

Tags: .net, arrays, linq, sorting

i have a integer array

```
int[] arr = { 50, 20, 170, 100, 10, 150 }

int start = 50;
```

To select all ascending nos starting from `50`, i am using.

```
arr.where(x => x > 50);
```

it returns `50, 170, 100, 150`
But, can i want to exclude `170` from the list, because it will not from a ascending ordered list.

Another eg: 1,7,3,18,20
This will result in 2 sets: 1, 7, 18, 20 and 1,3,18,20

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "select all ascending nos"? You need to be clearer about your requirements. (Why exclude 170 rather than excluding 100 and 150, for example?)

Comment: Are you after an ordered list? your question is not clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort an int array with orderby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404735/sort-an-int-array-with-orderby)

Comment: hi, i am trying to filter the list so that the output will be only a subset of numbers that is in perfect ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean get all the numbers that 50 can go into?

```
int[] arr = { 50, 20, 170, 100, 10, 150 }

int start = 50;

var results = arr.Where(x => x % start == 0).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Or do you mean get all numbers greater than or equal to 50 and go into it?

```
int[] arr = { 50, 20, 170, 100, 10, 150 }

int start = 50;

var results = arr.Where(x => x >= start && x % start == 0).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Both give you 50, 100 and 150

Comment: NO, not a factor of 50. it can be any number.

Comment: Also, the original order should not be altered.